# Is Google ARcore session can be saved in android application

Tags: android, arcore

I am trying to save the plane /object on it and position. 
so that when I will start my application again so same plane and object position will draw automatically.

Can any one help to understand AREA DESCRIPTION FILE in tango. 
Is same can be used in ARCore?
if yes please share the demo and example.

Or is possible to maintain same view after close and open camera in Ar core

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I save ar data for reuse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46304053/can-i-save-ar-data-for-reuse)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referring to maintaining the state when you re-open the application again in the same Environment. This will be fixed by Google automatically when you resume the previous session in its stable version of ARCore. It has been quoted [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Session.html#pause()). Hope this helps! :)

EDIT: Check out Developer Preview 2, it had the functionality I mentioned above.

Comment: hi Teja, thanks for reply, but I want to save the plane and object which i have placed. so I can see same when reboot my device or cloSe application and open again.

Comment: Then I guess you can somehow make the session object serializable and write it to disk and read it back. Because after reading it, you can resume it and things go back to normal as far as Google mentioned!

Comment: The resume and pause function you are describing is only for short interruptions like a device rotation change or incoming phone calls. You can not use this for saving a scene. This is only possible with the deprecated Tango SDK and Area Description Files. I hope ARCore will get this feature soon too.

Comment: @Christian D Yeah, it is now the situation. But at the time of the post (ARCore Developer Preview 1), the feature was still in development and I was expecting a Tango like feature, but nonetheless let's probably wait for it! 

Comment: Is it possible now with the new updates? I'm trying to do the same but seems like cloud anchors are the best alternative to re-create the scene in AR-Core. Let me know if you have a better solution for this. @TejaKonjeti